# Java generics - Don't allow subclasses

Tags: java, generics, subclass, type-inference

I have a question about generics. So lets say I have 3 classes "Foo", "Bar" (which is a subclass of Foo), a class "Factory" and an interface "TestInterface". 
I want to write a generic method, that only allows objects which "directly" implement the interface, so no subclasses. 
It is pretty hard for me, since Java8 seems to be "smarter" than Java7.

So heres an example:

```
public interface TestInterface<T extends TestInterface<T>> {

}
```

---

```
public class Foo implements TestInterface<Foo>{

}
```

---

```
public class Bar extends Foo {

}
```

---

```
public class Factory {

   public static <T extends TestInterface<T>> T doSth(T arg) {
       return arg;
   }
}
```

Okay, these are my classes. Now in the `doSth(T arg)` method I want to allow Foo-objects in this case, since it's the only class which "directly" implements the Interface.

Obviously sth like this won't compile now:

```
Bar b = Factory.doSth(new Bar());
```

since Bar doesnt implement `TestInterface<Bar>`.

Okay my problem now is, that this line will compile without any issues:

```
Foo f = Factory.doSth(new Bar());
```

Even tho the generic parameter is T and T should implement the interface with its own class (sorry, dont really know how to say it, hope you know what I mean), the compiler accepts "Bar" as a parameter.

So the compiler must behave like "okay Bar doesn't fit, but maybe a superclass would fit." And then it "sees" that it works with the superlcass "Foo". 
And then the Bar will be treated like a Foo, since every Bar is some kind of a Foo or sth like that?? At least that's how I imagine it.

Well, if I try to compile the line with Java7, it fails. So it seems like Java8 is a little bit smarter with the type-erasure?!

Is there any way in Java8 to not allow subclasses, so that this won't compile?:

```
Foo f = Factory.doSth(new Bar());
```

Hope you understand my problem, I'm rarely writing in English.

Greets

Comment: If you want `Foo f = Factory.doSth(new Bar());` to not compile, then Bar must not implement TestInterface<Foo>, which means it must not extend Foo..

Comment: If `Bar` subclasses `Foo`, then an instance of `Bar` _is_ an instance of `Foo`, and the instance of `Bar` must be accepted whenever a `Foo` is accepted.  Why don't you want a `Bar` to be acceptable here?

Comment: @immibis
Thanks for your answer. So with Bar beeing a subclass of Foo its not possible? 
In Java7 it wasnt working, do you know why they changed it, or is there anything to read about this new "feature".

Comment: @rgettman:
Its not sth i really need. Was just a small test for myself to understand generics a little bit better, since its pretty new to me. Was wondering if there is a way, since in Java7 this thing didnt work.

Comment: @FelRPI The difference is how type inferencing works in both the versions, which have changed in Java 8. In fact, the type inferencing in Java 8 has been improved somewhat.

Comment: JLS 8 has a complete [chapter on type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html), whereas in JLS 7, it's just [a subsection somewhere](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7)

Comment: @Rohit Jain
I was about to ask, if i could read something bout the Java8 changes regarding type inferencing. Thanks alot, will read that now.

Comment: On my machine, using Java 1.8.0_40, none of your lines compile. Are you sure about your example? Which Java version exactly are you using?

Comment: Yea im sure about my code. Im using Java 1.8.0_25. My code is exactly the one from the first post. I just added the main-method to the Factory. 

`public static void main(String[] args) {
  Bar b = Factory.doSth(new Bar()); //doesnt work
 
  Foo f = Factory.doSth(new Bar()); //works
 }`

Comment: @FelRPI `Foo f = Factory.<Foo>doSth(new Bar());` should work (explicitly specifying the type parameter) in Java 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `Foo f = Factory.doSth(new Bar());` works in Java 8 and not Java 7 is because Java 8 has better type inference. In Java 7 the type is inferred to:

```
Foo f = Factory.<Bar>doSth(new Bar());
```

`Bar` doesn't implement `TestInterface<Bar>`, but it does implement `TestInterface<Foo>` by inheritance. Java 8's type inference got a boost, and the type will be inferred to:

```
Foo f = Factory.<Foo>doSth(new Bar());
```

Note that `Factory.<Foo>doSth()` expects a `Foo` as argument so `new Bar()` is implicitly cast to `Foo` which works fine.

I'm afraid there's no way around this. You will always be able to upcast an object to its super class. You could make `Foo` `final`, but that disallows subclassing of `Foo` entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that such a case does exist; `Bar` is 'conceptually' a subclass of `Foo`, but we don't want to let them share a same method `doSth()`. 
It is not exactly same but, similary, sharing an `equals()` method among super-sub classes should be avoided in many cases, in order to keep symmetry and transitivity of equivalence relationship. (details are in Item 8 of Effective Java 2nd ed. by J.B.)

So far I failed to find a good solution with a description of generic parameters. (Java's type system, like other typical OO languages', seems to basically assume that every pair of super and sub classes should share the super class's methods by default.) Instead, I found that throwing away inheritance will be a possible solution in this case, as follows,

```
public class Bar  { // using composition, instead of inheritance
  Foo Bar(Foo f) {
     this.f = f;
  }
  // here, definitions of delegated methods for each of f's methods
  // see details in Item 16 of Effective Java 2nd ed. by J.B.

  Foo asFoo(){ 
     return f;
  }
}
```

With this modification of `Bar`, we can get a compile time error here,

```
Foo b = Factory.doSth(new Bar(new Foo())); // a compile time error occurs
```

even when we're using `<Foo>` in JDK7.

```
Foo b = Factory.<Foo>doSth(new Bar(new Foo())); // a compile time error occurs
```

On the other hands, if necessary, we can use `asFoo()` to avoid this error.

```
Foo b = Factory.<Foo>doSth(new Bar(new Foo()).asFoo()); // no compile time error
```